# How to do "mysqladmin flush-hosts" on server?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, database-connection, flush

I have a hosting account, on database section i have "MySQL® Databases",
"MySQL® Database Wizard","phpMyAdmin" and "Remote MySQL" Options

Error i am getting is

```
Database ErrorHost 'adonis.havehost.com' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'
```

Answer (score 17):

Write a server application that sends the query:

```
FLUSH HOSTS
```

to MySQL.

If you have shell access to the server, you can login and do:

```
mysql -u root -p -e 'flush hosts'
```

Comment: i didn't get you what you mean 'writing server application' ?

Comment: E.g. a PHP script. I assumed you don't have command line access to the server.

Comment: No, i don't hav a shell access.

Comment: Actually, I just realized my answer won't work, since it requires making a client connection to the database, and that's what's blocked. You need shell access to run the `mysqladmin` command. Check your web hosting service to see if they have a way of doing what you want from their portal.

Answer (score 7):

This must solve your issue.

```
mysql -u root -p -e 'flush hosts'
```

Answer (score 4):

mysql -u root -p -e 'flush hosts'
And you can even contract your server provider

Answer (score 3):

In MySql,run the following query:

```
FLUSH HOSTS;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [mysqladmin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqladmin.html) you can execute this command:

mysqladmin flush-hosts;

and

mysqladmin flush-status;

This will remove the error shown by your MySQL server.

Comment: i have mentioned all the available options in database section. there isn't mysqladmin. should i download it? or show me where can i run command. i don't that can run on phpmyadmin>SQL

Answer (score 1):

log in to your server by putty SSH, and just type this command

`mysql -u root -p -e 'flush hosts'`

and enter your root password after that your host name will be flushed , with out showing any massage in Shell.